# can refrence null foreign key to self table in mysql innodb table?

Tags: php, mysql

i have comment table which have self relation on id and parent-id column.
each root comment have NULL value (or 0) on parent-id filed. i try to relate them in phpmyadmin and i do that, but when i insert comment with parent-id of NULL mysql give error.
can we do such a thing in mysql?

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`hezar`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `comment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`)    
REFERENCES `comment` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: No, because there must be foreign key column specified and it must point to existing entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be working just fine. But you have to allow NULL values for `parent`. You can't insert 0 because this is a constraint violation. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT NOT NULL, ref_id INT, PRIMARY KEY(id), FOREIGN KEY (ref_id) REFERENCES mytable(id) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDb;
# working inserts
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2, 1);

# failing insert
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3, 0);
```

Comment: yes i allow NULL value, and it didn't work. i run your code and it didn't run too

Comment: This is a little surprising, it worked for me, I'm using mysql 5.5. Not even the first two inserts worked? The third one was not supposed to work.